# Files improperly aligned after transfer via FTP

Tags: python, sftp

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 box (external server) and there is a bunch of python files. Whenever I tried to FTP these files to my local machines and open the python files the code is not aligned properly.

I believe during the transfer the alignment gets corrupted.

How can I fix this issue? I'm in Mac and use `cyberduck` to transfer these files.

If you notice the try statement is mis-aligned after I ftp the code. This is just a snapshot. Many lines are not aligned properly:

```
    for pano in test_images:
    import time
    #time.sleep(30)
    print "Reading ",pano
    t_start = dt.datetime.now()
        try:
            orig_img = cv2.imread(pano)[:,:,:3]
            '''
            round_y = orig_img.shape[0]%J["h_stride"]
            r_y = J["h_stride"]-round_y if round_y > J["h_stride"]/2 else -round_y
            round_x = orig_img.shape[1]%J["w_stride"]
            r_x = J["w_stride"]-round_x if round_x > J["w_stride"]/2 else -round_x
            orig_img = imresize(orig_img, ( orig_img.shape[0]+round_y, orig_img.shape[0]+round_x) )
            '''
        except:
            continue
```

Remote file:

```
for pano in test_images:
            import time
            #time.sleep(30)
            print "Reading ",pano
            t_start = dt.datetime.now()
            try:
                orig_img = cv2.imread(pano)[:,:,:3]
                '''
                round_y = orig_img.shape[0]%J["h_stride"]
                r_y = J["h_stride"]-round_y if round_y > J["h_stride"]/2 else -round_y
                round_x = orig_img.shape[1]%J["w_stride"]
                r_x = J["w_stride"]-round_x if round_x > J["w_stride"]/2 else -round_x
                orig_img = imresize(orig_img, ( orig_img.shape[0]+round_y, orig_img.shape[0]+round_x) )
                '''
            except:
                continue
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66258/discussion-between-terdon-and-user1050619).

Comment: This [ended up](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66258/discussion-between-terdon-and-user1050619) being an issue with how the OP's editor (sublime) dealt with tabs.